# Sort changes/edited list of object data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, lodash

Let's say I have this object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "lineNo": "222",
        "description": "hello"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "lineNo": "765",
        "description": "hmmm"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "lineNo": "112",
        "description": "last"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and then I change `description` in id 30 from `hmmm` to:

```
  {
    "id": 30,
    "lineNo": "765",
    "description": "should be first"
  },
```

and it will become like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "lineNo": "222",
        "description": "hello"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "lineNo": "765",
        "description": "should be first"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "lineNo": "112",
        "description": "last"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I changes/sort after I edited the object? I want the recent edited object at the top like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "id": 30,
        "lineNo": "765",
        "description": "should be first"
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "lineNo": "222",
        "description": "hello"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "lineNo": "112",
        "description": "last"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I also using Lodash library, if anyone know any example with lodash or native  please refer me to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is interesting. A hint, `array.prototype.every` would get you started.

Comment: @Mouser, more [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: You need to keep trace of the changed objects. If you have control to change the code that will do these changes or can place a hook there, then you just need to keep a queue with the objects changes and then a simple algorithm to take the items changed then all items remaining in the array in that order. However if you cannot control when these changes occur, then you might need to use Object.observe.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha, an observer is also a nice, but tricky, solution.

Comment: Why not just swap the updated element with the first element like so: `[data.result[0], data.result[k]] = [data.result[k], data.result[0]]`? Of course, that is given you know when the changes happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the item with the wanted `id` with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it and [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) the item to the array.

```js
function updateArrayAndMove(array, id, key, value) {
    array.some(function (o, i, a) {
        if (o.id === id) {
            o[key] = value;
            a.unshift(a.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

var object = { data: { result: [{ id: 25, lineNo: "222", description: "hello" }, { id: 30, lineNo: "765", description: "hmmm" }, { id: 31, lineNo: "112", description: "last" }] } };

updateArrayAndMove(object.data.result, 30, 'description', 'should be first');
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If the OP is using lodash, then `getIndexOfId` call can be replaced with `_.findIndex(object.data.result, item => item.id === 30)`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var object =
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "lineNo": "222",
        "description": "hello"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "lineNo": "765",
        "description": "should be first"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "lineNo": "112",
        "description": "last"
      }
    ]
  }
}

function changeElement(id, key, value)
{
  var changedId = -1;
  var arrReturned = object.data.result.forEach(function(element, index){
    if (element['id'] == id)
    {
      element[key] = value;
      changedId = index; //push the changed index into the array
    }
  });
  
  //element has changed
  //use splice to change the order
  var element = object.data.result.splice(changedId, 1);
  object.data.result.unshift(element[0])
  
  console.log(object)
}

changeElement(30, "description", "should be first");
```

A possible solution to your problem, using forEach to change and splice and unshift to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

All this reply gave me some idea. Here's how you do it with lodash. You must know id object that you just updated.

```
var object =
    {
      "data": {
        "result": [
          {
            "id": 25,
            "lineNo": "222",
            "description": "hello"
          },
          {
            "id": 30,
            "lineNo": "765",
            "description": "should be first"
          },
          {
            "id": 31,
            "lineNo": "112",
            "description": "last"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    var filteredObj = _.remove(object.data.result, function(o) {
        return o.id == '30'; // must know object id
    });
    object.data.result.unshift(filteredObj[0]);

    console.log("mutated object.data.result", object.data.result)
```

Example : https://fiddle.jshell.net/uLqfuqn1/

Reference : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove

Thanks to all that reply.